# Exceptions vs Error codes

Tags: c#, .net, exception, architecture, enums

Right now we have a set of so called 'services' - classes, that have methods with common signature: their result type have a property T? Error, where T is enum.
And we have a separate enum for each method with a set of values defined for specific method.

This works rather good as long as the final place where we use these services' methods from is controllers' actions — these errors are returned to client, where they are handled by javascript.

But sometime we want to compose some methods of calls of other services' methods, and it is the place where I seem to have a problem.
Let's say we have service's method A(), that has error of type `AError`. And this A() method calls internally method B() that has an error of type `BError`.

First of all, we have to map possible `BError` to `AError`.
And also it is possible to forget to inspect B's error, and its presence will remain unobserved.

Of cource I know that it is common to use exceptions to indicate that a method has failed.
Right now all controllers have a filter that intercepts unhandled exceptions and returns an answer with just single property Error with value 'InternalServerError'.
But if we start to use exceptions we will loose one feature that I consider important: now a possible set of method's errors is explicitly specified in its signature, and this will be lost in case of we use exceptions.
I know that there is a tag in xml-documentation to list exception types, but it is only documentation, it is not checked by a compiler.

Also I do not understand how to use exceptions on our code:
Let's say we have some method that first checks order's status. Right now it returns 'InvalidOrderStatus' error if order's status is invalid for current action.
If we use exceptions, we can create an exception `InvalidOrderStatusException`, but how can we know that code that we call internally throws it?

We can also create a mnemonic rule: method A should have error type AError, and inside it should throw some generic exception (let's say, `ErrorException<>`), parametrized by this AError. And we can intercept this generic exception `ErrorException<AError>` in all A's calls and observe its error code. But this will not be checked by a compiler: Method A can throw any other exception, or `ErrorException<>`, but parametrized by some other error code.

So my question is: what is the best way to a) always know what kind of exceptions method can throw and what kind of errors it can return, and b) not be able to forget to observe method's result error?

Comment: You can add some custom or predefined attributes to mark possible exceptions, but why do you need to know them?

Comment: If I translate error codes to exceptions, they will be business exceptions, and in any case I would have to catch them in controller and translate to error code, that will be later consumed by javascript handler or server response. And in javascript I can, for instance, have different error messages for different error codes.

Answer (score 0):

How about exchanging enum `AError` with something like this:

```
class ErrorHolder<T> // T would be AError, BError
{
   T ErrorCode {get;}
   object[] InnerErrors {get;}
   // other payload could go here like inner exceptions etc.
}
```

Thus you have the enumerated error codes which can be somehow checked plus you can add whatever payload you need.

Comment: This the very way we use it now. Each method result is a class implementing interface IHaveError<TError> { T? Error {get;set;} }

Comment: Let the result have a property of type `ErrorHolder`, which itself contains the enum.

Comment: What benefits would this approach give? What should I store in InnerErrors? If errors (like same ErrorHolders or exceptions) of methods called inside, I do not think this is a good idea as caller would have to know not only how to handle errors of its direct callees, but of their callees too, thus becoming highly dependent on their changes.

Comment: But if you map every ErrorB to some ErrorA, you force the caller of A to handle each ErrorB anyway. If you had an `ErrorHolder` you could also add an error category for instance. This somehow mimics the types for exception. The user will then be able to handle all errors of a certain category at once. May it's best if you post some code and intended usage.

Comment: When a method A calls inside method B, it maps every value of BError to some AError. And thus A's callers do not need to handle BErrors, only AErrors.

Comment: Ok, but instead of lets say 10 AErrors and 5 BErrors, the user has to handle 15 AErrors?

Comment: No, AError have a set of enum values. Each BError is mapped to one of these AError's values. So A's caller would have to handle AError's only, as method A returns AError only, not BError or their union.

Comment: So you map BErrors to existing AErrors (i.e. they are used in other situations as well)? Or have you one special AError for every BError?

Comment: If callers on A should know about internal BError that happened inside of A while calling B, there would be a value in AError, in the other case I would use some AError's value that existed before and is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Create some base exception with desired behaviuor, provide base mechanizm for it's handling, processing and conversion to a result that's being sent to javascript. It doesn't mean that you need to know a list of all possbile exceptions of your method (probaly such list will always be a lie because of possbile non-business exceptions). So derived exceptions can be just a substitutions for error codes, containing specific messages and other data (error code :) ). As you say - "a possible set of method's errors is explicitly specified in its signature" imho it's not an important feature. You should be "object oriented" think of general exception handling (at controller method code level like HandleError(ExecuteService()) or at action filter level). Also, you error codes can be appear not an exceptions but some "execution results" with success or fail status, it's not an exceptional behaviour like "entity not found" but an expected result from service. In this case I use the following code

```
public class ExecutionResult
{
    public ExecutionResult() : this(null)
    {
    }
    public ExecutionResult(ExecutionResult result)
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
            Success = result.Success;
            Errors = new List<ErrorInfo>(result.Errors);
        }
        else
        {
            Errors = new List<ErrorInfo>();
        }
    }
    private bool? _success;
    public bool Success
    {
        get { return _success ?? Errors.Count == 0; }
        set { _success = value; }
    }
    public IList<ErrorInfo> Errors { get; private set; }
}

/*T is for result (any business object)*/
public class ExecutionResult<T> : ExecutionResult
{
    public ExecutionResult() : this(null)
    {
    }
    public ExecutionResult(T result) : this(null)
    {
        Value = result;
    }
    public ExecutionResult(ExecutionResult result)
        : base(result)
    {
        var r = result as ExecutionResult<T>;
        if (r != null)
        {
            Value = r.Value;
        }
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Let's say we have a very complex controller action, that calls inside a lot of other methods, some of them can throw a business exception (saying a business exception I mean for example, that it should be shown to a user as a message like 'Order not found', 'Order is invalid status', 'Forbidden' etc). How can I, not exploring all the call tree of this action, provide a list of possible error codes to our web developer so that she can handle them, displaying unique message for each of them? Error codes, while having several drawbacks I've mentioned before, provides a way to list possible errors

Comment: I see, well, the list of all possible errors is a part of software specification. Also you can use some attributes for methods that throw exceptions and generate the list of errors with some unit test, which finds usages of this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: what is the best way to a) always know what kind of
>   exceptions method can throw and what kind of errors it can return, and
>   b) not be able to forget to observe method's result error?

To address "a":

It's hard to do this at compile time. But you can do it via reflection at runtime. See the static `enumValues` field in the `ErrorHandlerFor<T>` class.

To address "b", you could do it like this:

In brief: instead of a `switch` after the call, you prepare error handlers (formerly in the `case` parts) as lambdas and put all of them in a `ErrorHandlerFor<T>` class and pass this to the function. This adds the additional benefit of giving feedback to the function whether to continue or abort.

You can also think of this like this:

Assume you want to give some work to a fellow. This work can fail in several ways.

Traditionally you gave the fellow the work and waited till it was finished, maybe with errors. You then handled the errors if necessary.

Now you give the fellow also some "phone numbers" to call when certain errors arise. The answer to the call may even guide the fellow if the work can be continued or needs to be aborted.

```
enum AError
{
    AError1,
    AError2,
    AError3,
    AError4,
    AError5,

}


delegate bool SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T>(T error, object someOtherPayload);

interface IHandle<T>
{
    bool Handle(T error, object someOtherPayload); // return true if handled;
}

class ErrorHandlerFor<T> : IHandle<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T>> handlers;
    private static T[] enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToArray();
    public ErrorHandlerFor(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<T>, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T>>> handlers)
        : this(handlers.SelectMany(h => h.Key.Select(key => new KeyValuePair<T, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T>>(key, h.Value))))
    {
    }

    public ErrorHandlerFor(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<T>, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T>>> handlers, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T> fallbackHandler)
        : this(handlers.SelectMany(h => h.Key.Select(key => new KeyValuePair<T, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T>>(key, h.Value))), fallbackHandler)
    {
    }



    public ErrorHandlerFor(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T>>> handlers)
    {
        this.handlers = new Dictionary<T, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T>>();
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            Debug.Assert(handler.Value != null);
            this.handlers.Add(handler.Key, handler.Value);
        }

        checkHandlers();
    }

    public ErrorHandlerFor(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T>>> handlers, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T> fallbackHandler)
    {
        this.handlers = new Dictionary<T, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<T>>();
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            Debug.Assert(handler.Value != null);
            this.handlers.Add(handler.Key, handler.Value);
        }
        foreach (var enumValue in enumValues)
        {
            if (this.handlers.ContainsKey(enumValue) == false)
            {
                this.handlers.Add(enumValue, fallbackHandler);
            }
        }

        checkHandlers();
    }



    private void checkHandlers()
    {
        foreach (var enumValue in enumValues)
        {
            Debug.Assert(handlers.ContainsKey(enumValue));
        }
    }

    public bool Handle(T error, object someOtherPayload)
    {
        return handlers[error](error: error, someOtherPayload: someOtherPayload);
    }
}



class Test
{
    public static void test()
    {
        var handler = new ErrorHandlerFor<AError>(
            new[]{
                new KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<AError>, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<AError>>(
                new []{AError.AError1, AError.AError2, AError.AError4,},
                (AError error, object payload) => { Console.WriteLine(@"handled error 1, 2 or 4!"); return true;}
                ),
                new KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<AError>, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<AError>>(
                new []{AError.AError3, AError.AError5,},
                (AError error, object payload) => { Console.WriteLine(@"could not handle error 3 or 5!"); return false;}
                ),
            }
            );

        var result = Services.foo(handler);


        var incompleteHandlerButWithFallbackThatWillPassTheTest = new ErrorHandlerFor<AError>(
            new[]{
                new KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<AError>, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<AError>>(
                new []{AError.AError1, AError.AError2, AError.AError4,},
                (AError error, object payload) => { Console.WriteLine(@"handled error 1, 2 or 4!"); return true;}
                ),
                new KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<AError>, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<AError>>(
                new []{AError.AError5},
                (AError error, object payload) => { Console.WriteLine(@"could not handle error 3 or 5!"); return false;}
                ),
            }
            // AError.AError3 is not handled!  => will go in fallback
            , (AError error, object payload) => { Console.WriteLine(@"could not handle error in fallback!"); return false; }
            );

        var result2 = Services.foo(incompleteHandlerButWithFallbackThatWillPassTheTest);


        var incompleteHandlerThatWillBeDetectedUponInstantiation = new ErrorHandlerFor<AError>(
            new[]{
                new KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<AError>, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<AError>>(
                new []{AError.AError1, AError.AError2, AError.AError4,},
                (AError error, object payload) => { Console.WriteLine(@"handled error 1, 2 or 4!"); return true;}
                ),
                new KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<AError>, SingleErrorHandlerDelegate<AError>>(
                new []{AError.AError3},
                (AError error, object payload) => { Console.WriteLine(@"could not handle error 3 or 5!"); return false;}
                ),
            } // AError.AError5 is not handled!  => will trigger the assertion!
            );

    }

}


class Services
{
    public static Result foo(IHandle<AError> errorHandler)
    {
        Debug.Assert(errorHandler != null);

        // raise error...
        var myError = AError.AError1;
        var handled = errorHandler.Handle(error: myError, someOtherPayload: "hello");
        if (!handled)
            return new Result();

        // maybe proceed

        var myOtherError = AError.AError3;
        errorHandler.Handle(error: myOtherError, someOtherPayload: 42); //we'll return anyway in this case...
        return new Result();

    }



    public class Result
    {

    }
}
```